# How can I run my Netbeans IDE in Fedora 15 just after auto login? So that I do not see any other gnome details

Tags: linux, fedora, boot, fullscreen, kiosk

After /etc/gdm/custom.conf modification. I want to startup in full screen my application such as IDE or Kiosk apps. Without showing up Gnome desktop taskbar etc.

How can I do that in my Fedora 15? I have tried such as this but did not worked.

```
vi /etc/rc.local
java -jar /tmp/myapplication.jar --fullscreenkiosk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a script that starts only what you want, and put it in an appropriate location like `/usr/local/bin`.  For instance, this script starts the Metacity window manager (you'll experience some difficulties if you don't run at least a window manager) and Eclipse.  (There are some fancier things you can do, for instance [in this example I showed how to restart the program if it is exited](https://superuser.com/questions/265189/embedded-vnc-session/265211#265211).)

`/usr/local/bin/eclipse-kiosk.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

metacity &
eclipse
```

Then, make it executable by running `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/eclipse-kiosk.sh`.  Now, create a desktop file for it in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

`/usr/share/xsessions/eclipse-kiosk.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=XSession
Exec=/usr/local/bin/eclipse-kiosk.sh
TryExec=/usr/local/bin/eclipse-kiosk.sh
Name=Eclipse Kiosk
```

Now, `Eclipse Kiosk` will appear in the GDM sessions menu and GDM can be configured to log in using it however you want.